# Left justifying section or a div

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to left justify my section below my vertical menu bar below my horizontal menu bar but can't seem to identify where I'm going wrong.

I've used display and float but they seem not to work on the vertical section.

Any ideas? Its probably me overlooking a small detail

```css
/* Section - Horizontal menu bar */
.horizontal_menu_bar_section {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  background: #FFCC00;
}

/* Section - Vertical menu bar */
.vertical_menu_bar_section {
  float: left;
  color: #999999;
  background: #FF0000;
  font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Tahoma, Sans-serif;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="horizontal_menu_bar_section">
  <ul id="menu_bar">

    <li><a href="#">DASHBOARD</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">UPLOAD</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">OPTION 3</a>
      <ul class="noJS">
        <li><a href="#">OPTION 3 A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OPTION 3 B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OPTION 3 C</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">OPTION 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">OPTION 5</a></li>

  </ul>
  <section>

    <section class="vertical_menu_bar_section">
      <div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
          <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
          <li><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
          <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
          <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <section>
```

Comment: it works right in snippet

Comment: @sanoj lawrence: Just realised my problem was I wasn't utilising the property clear: both to prevent anything appearing to the right (or left of my sections).

The solution which worked for me was adding `clear: both;` and removing the `float: left;` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised my problem was I wasn't utilising the property clear: both to prevent anything appearing to the right (or left of my sections).

The solution which worked for me was adding `clear: both;` and removing the `float: left;` property.